# problem with installing plugins for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, installation

Each time Iam trying to install a plug in I get these errors:

> No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.activation,1.1.0.v201005080500
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.mail,1.4.0.v201005080615
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.xml.rpc,1.1.0.v201005080400
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.axis,1.4.0.v201005080400
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.discovery,0.2.0.v201004190315
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.6.1.v20100913-2020
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.query,1.4.0.v20100428-2315-218Z7w311A142A1142
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.transaction,1.4.0.v20100331-1738
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.transaction,1.4.0.v20100428-2315-377-8s734C3E7D15D6B
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.transaction.ui,1.4.0.v20090819-1300
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.validation,1.4.0.v20100428-2315
>     No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.validation,1.4.0.v20100428-2315-479-9oB56N5BBR6LCA6
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.workspace,1.4.0.v20100224-1706
>     No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.workspace,1.4.0.v20100428-2315-36-8s734C367E3CBC7
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.6.1.v20100712-1224
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.j2ee,1.1.302.v201004131604
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.web,1.1.302.v201003181725
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d.doc.isv,3.5.0.v20100519-2050
>     No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.6.1.v20100908-1100-4507w31211A2403131
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.draw2d.sdk,3.6.1.v20100908-1100-7A7G18yE5F-8K8N4I8E558B48x42
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d.source,3.6.1.v20100913-2020
>     No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.draw2d.source,3.6.1.v20100908-1100-4507w31211A2403131
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef.all,3.6.1.v20100908-1100-787D17PhSyGcDBx8Zy_MhtyNUO45
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.doc.isv,3.5.0.v20100519-2050
>     No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef.examples,3.6.1.v20100908-1100-7G7T1BgJ9E99iCg4FPEO
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.flow,3.6.0.v20100616-1515
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.flow.source,3.6.0.v20100616-1515
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.logic,3.6.1.v20100908-2020
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.logic.source,3.6.1.v20100908-2020
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.shapes,3.6.0.v20100616-1515
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.shapes.source,3.6.0.v20100616-1515
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef.examples.source,3.6.1.v20100908-1100
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.text,3.6.0.v20100616-1515
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.text.source,3.6.0.v20100616-1515
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.examples.ui.pde,3.5.0.v20100519-2050
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef,3.6.1.v20100908-1100-777B181A3Bz-6B663E7974242
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef.sdk,3.6.1.v20100908-1100-7G7R2A5WNcBQPZgXAHiSXMXYaKPI
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef.source,3.6.1.v20100712-1224
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.gef.source,3.6.1.v20100908-1100-777B181A3Bz-6B663E7974242
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.zest.core,1.2.0.v20100525-1225
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.zest.core.source,1.2.0.v20100525-1225
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.zest,1.2.0.v20100519-2050-67808yE5F-8HAH4HECF4242
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.zest.layouts,1.1.0.v20100616-1515
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.zest.layouts.source,1.1.0.v20100616-1515
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.zest.sdk,1.2.0.v20100519-2050-67908COKMFAKPYIEUdUVWhXYN8VN
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.zest.source,1.2.0.v20100519-2050-67808yE5F-8HAH4HECF4242

Can any one please help. BTW, throwing everything away and reinstall eclipse from scratch is really not an option for me.

Thank you alot.

Comment: There are a lot of questions and answers on this `No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,...` You might want to search for that string and try those with most answers. In my case this answer worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15897080/5108777 (number 2 in particular).

Answer (score 0):

What were you trying to do when you got this message?

Why is reinstalling Eclipse not an option? If you suspect that Eclipse is corrupt, uninstalling/reinstalling will not affect your workspace.

You could unzip a copy of Eclipse to another location on your machine and use it to use your existing workspace in parallel if you're worried about deleting your current Eclipse install.

Comment: I was trying to install the android plugin.
I'v installed eclipse relatively a long time ago and installed alot of plugins and things for SVN so if I throw my current installation I'am afraid that I have to do every thing from scratch. And that would cost me alot of time!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your plugin is ADT 8.0.1 (Update the title of your thread to attract more answers)

"Dependencies:

ADT 8.0.1 is designed for use with SDK Tools r8. If you haven't already installed SDK Tools r8 into your SDK, use the Android SDK and AVD Manager to do so."

Have you done this?

Installation also varies by version of Eclipse. See here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html