# What to do about Eclipse's "No repository found containing: ..." error messages?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm running Eclipse's Helios EE bundle on Linux to which I added the subversive plugins, the m2e Maven integration and the Mylin connector for Trac. For the last couple of weeks I've been trying to install updates, and every time I get back a message like

```
No repository found containing <something or other>
```

The latest one was

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn,0.7.9.I20110318-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.core,0.7.9.I20110523-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.help,0.7.9.I20110318-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.mylyn,0.7.9.I20110318-1700
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.team.svn.ui,0.7.9.I20110523-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn,0.7.9.I20110523-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.mylyn,0.7.9.I20110523-1700
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.team.svn.resource.ignore.rules.jdt,0.7.9.I20110523-1700
```

What does it all mean and how do I fix that? If Eclipse has been able to contact the repositories to check for new files, why isn't it able to download those files from those some repositories? Or does the error message mean something entirely different?

Comment: For anypoint studio (a derivative of eclipse IDE) I had to disable everything but mule's own sites. It was the only way to update IDE

Comment: I was getting a similar error to this with Anypoint studio (eclipse variant) in the end I renamed my workspace and on the next start the issue was gone. I figure its either a caching issue or perhaps the workspace gets corrupt in some way.

Answer (score 479):

Go to **Help → Install new software → Here uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”**

Eclipse will prompt that the content isn't authorized or something like that. just ignore and continue. then everything will be OK.

At least this trick resolved my problems similar like this:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
action=). No repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf,2.6.0.v20120917-0436 No repository found
containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ant,2.7.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.8.0.v20120917-0436 No repository
found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.8.1.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.8.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ui,2.6.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.8.0.v20120911-0500 No repository
found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.7.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.converter,2.5.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.2.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.databinding.edit,1.2.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.8.1.v20120911-0500 No repository
found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change,2.8.0.v20120911-0500 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change.edit,2.5.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.8.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.editor,2.8.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi,2.8.0.v20120911-0500 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.8.0.v20120917-0436 No repository
found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.8.0.v20120917-0436 No repository
found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.exporter,2.6.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer,2.7.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.ecore,2.6.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.java,2.6.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.importer.rose,2.6.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping,2.7.0.v20120917-0436 No repository
found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore,2.6.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore.editor,2.6.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2ecore,2.7.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2ecore.editor,2.5.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml,2.7.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore2xml.ui,2.6.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ui,2.6.0.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.300.v201111030424
No repository found containing:
osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.ui,1.4.300.v201111030424
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore,2.8.1.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ecore.ui,2.8.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen,2.8.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.codegen.ui,2.7.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.common,2.8.0.v20120911-0500
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.common.ui,2.7.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.converter,2.8.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.databinding.edit,1.2.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.databinding,1.2.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit,2.8.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore.editor,2.8.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.ecore,2.8.1.v20120911-0500
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.edit,2.8.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui,2.8.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf,2.8.1.v20120917-0436 No
repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore.editor,2.7.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ecore,2.7.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping,2.7.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.emf.mapping.ui,2.7.0.v20120917-0436
No repository found containing:
org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common.fproj,3.4.0.v201202292300-377F8N8s735555393B7B
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm running Eclipse Juno 4.2 on Windows 7 and I was encountering the same errors on every installation attempt.

Comment: Using this I could install new software, but the problem when trying to update existing software remains.

Comment: I was about to re-install my ADT+Eclipse bundle... this answer saved that effort.

Comment: Where is this checkbox? I seem to remember something like this somewhere in the update process but don't see anything now. I check for updates and get a list of updates. All I can do is select which ones I want. Next it is a review screen, where I can't actually do anything except go back, cancel, or finish. I've also looked under preferences but can't find anything.

Comment: In 3.6, you have to open `Help`>`Install new software`, then uncheck the box there, and then perform the update from here directly by typing the websites.

Comment: Not a fix for Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Work for me, on install Android ADT in Eclipse Luna! Tks.

Comment: Very useful advice, it works for Vaadin 7 Design UI Alpha 0.6.5 Installation.

Comment: Worked for me on Luna

Comment: It also required a restart of Eclipse for this to work for me. Running Neon.

Comment: Worked on Eclipse Neon

Comment: Any idea how to do this in mac?

Answer (score 194):

Thanks to Fredrik for pointing to the original [bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290782). A comment by Richard Shu there describes several available solutions:

> 1. As Mauro said: "you have to remove and re-add the Eclipse Project Update
>      site, so that its metadata are re-calculated."  - works as workaround
> 2. Another workaround I found, is to edit the pre-defined URL link by adding
>      just a trailing “/” to the update site URL.
> 3. The third workaround I discoverd accidentaly is to do nothing, but to
>      uncheck the 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software'
>      before checking the URL link.

Option #2 worked for me. I went to `Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites`, then for each enabled site I added a `/` to the end of the URL (if it wasn't there already), then clicked `Reload`.

Comment: Option #2 seems to be the only one functional on Luna.

Comment: None of those options fixed my issue. Cannot update any existing plugins. :(

Comment: Eclipse Luna 4.4.2, Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers. Option #2 helped to me too. It is strange, that I must apply option #2 on fresh installation to install another one installation. Option #3 doesn't helped even if in previous another case it was successful choice.

Comment: Option #1 worked for me on Luna. I removed the site, closed all the dialog boces, tried an update (of course it failed but might be significant), added the site again, tried another update and it worked.

Comment: #2 made my eclipse mars to delete the repositories altogether for some reason

Comment: #2 helped updating STS 3.7.3 to 3.8

Comment: #1 worked for me. #2 deletes whichever ones I modify in Neon. #3 had no effect for me.

Comment: Option #2 seems to be the only one functional in Neon

Comment: Tried #2, but doing so removed it, so I added it back and then it seemed to work. But, then it failed again, and now all options aren't working.

Comment: Option #2 worked for me, while trying to install `m2eclipse-scala` connector.

Comment: I don't know why this issue still exists after 6 years! Tried #2 for _Mylyn 3.23_ update and it worked.

Comment: After adding `/` I lost all update sites.
So I applied [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49929002/2707864) **plus** the trailing `/` and it worked. I am not sure if it was because of the slash, because I ended up adding repos that were not listed there before, or both.

Comment: Option 1 Worked for me on Eclipse CDT 2021.06 (4.20.0)

Answer (score 53):

What you most likely has encountered is a [bug in Eclipse](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290782).

Luckily the solution is simple enough, remove the update site and install it again.

Comment: You suggestion worked for me, but I will say the linked bug doesn't seem match your suggestion as far as I can tell.  The issue has been closed as invalid.  Sure does sound like a bug to me if you have to remove the update site and add again.

Comment: So it appears from @nslntmnx comment that this hasn't been fixed in the latest release of Eclipse - Neon. What fun. :-(

Answer (score 29):

Me helped the following solution:

1. Go to Help->Software Updates, then select the Available Software tab and click the Manage Sites button
2. Use the Export button to export the sites to a bookmarks.xml file
3. Open the bookmarks.xml file in your favorite text editor, and add a trailing “/” to any of the site urls which are missing the “/” **or remove** on the end. Save the changes.
4. Back in the Manage Sites window within Eclipse, select all of the sites and click the Remove button
5. Now, click Import and load in the edited bookmarks.xml file

It was taken from this link [Devon Hillard's Digital Sanctuary](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/general/no-repository-found-containing-error-when-update-eclipse.html)

Comment: Editing the update sites (through Preferences, without exporting/importing) and adding a slash at the end of the URL helped in my case, thanks!

Comment: Wow. been struggling with this for awhile and this suggestion is working! Pazabo above gives a convenient way to do. Thanks so much! Was tearing my hair out.... ouch butafterwards on restart I have some exit code.. sigh.. I'm doomed.

Comment: pazabo's manual version worked for me too (Eclipse 4.6.2 neon)

Answer (score 10):

The updates that Eclipse has found have dependencies that need to be downloaded during the installation but which cannot currently be found. This may be a temporary network problem or some repo server being down (if you're lucky). But unfortunately, sometimes this simply means that the dependencies are not contained in the repositories that Eclipse is trying to download them from, at least that is what i have encountered every now and then (not annoyingly often though).

So either the failure is temporary and you should try again or you are out of luck and may have to use a manual installation procedure (download and unpack in plugins folder).

Maybe you can increase your success rate by adding the repositories that supposedly contain the artifacts in the 'Available Software Sites' dialogue.

I'm not 100% sure of that though. In fact, I would like to find a 'perfect' answer to this question myself.

What usually works quite well is installing plugins via the Eclipse Marketplace.

Oh and sometimes this helps: Uncheck some options (like OSGI in your case).

Comment: looks like in my specific case "check for updates..." returns newer plugins than those marked as the latest versions in the "install new software..." dialog.

Comment: could be that this has to do with the fact that eclipse indigo (successor of helios) has been released a couple of days ago. Can you explicitely specify older versions?

Answer (score 8):

Simple!!!!!!!!

Right click on eclipse folder and go to properties.
Uncheck checkbox "read only" if checked.
apply changes.click oK.

after go to  Help>Install new software>Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”.

Comment: Read only checkbox doesn't exist but thanks for reminding me about "Contact all update sites during install to find required software"

Comment: Lack of write permissions to directory where Eclipse/TI Code Composer Studio is installed was the root cause for the OPs error for me on Linux.

Comment: Just this didn't work for me but lead me to try accessing with a higher privilege, and solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

None of the other answers worked for me (Windows 10, Eclipse Neon). Running Eclipse as Administrator fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

What I did was:

1. I went to Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites, then for each enabled site I added a / to the end of the URL (if it wasn't there already), then clicked Reload as per @Hunternif answer. But the problem still persisted.
2. Then I disabled all the software sites and re-enalbed them one by one and ran updates to keep only those that worked. After step 2. the problem was solved. Now I have enabled only the update sites that do not give the error and updates work.

Answer (score 5):

I am trying to make an update for Spring STS 3.6.3 to the version 3.6.4 in Eclipse Luna (4.4.1) and I tried the following solution and it worked for me:

1. go to Help > Install new Softwares > Available software sites
2. Uncheck all and check only the sites SpringSource Update Site for Eclipse 4.4 it means that you check only the update site for your version of eclipse
3. And validate and make your update

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same issue since mid 2018. Performing a search, this issue has been reported since 2011.
I'm surprised workarounds are proposed for this. Unfortunately they havent't worked for me, **currently the only fix seems to completely reinstall Eclipse**. As the most upvoted suggestion here, many of the suggestions are contradicting, suggesting trial-error guesses.

Besides these workarounds, IMHO this requires a fix. We're in 2019 now, surely there is a way to fix this recurring issue? How can there not be a simple fix i.e. if repo URL not found: skip and continue with next URL / update (without aborting as critical error and preventing any other update)?

Answer (score 4):

On Juno (Build id: 20130225-0426), exporting update sites from 'Available software Sites", fixing the trailing "/" in the exported xml as described above, removing all sites and importing the fixed xml worked for me.
Described [here](http://www.digitalsanctuary.com/tech-blog/general/no-repository-found-containing-error-when-update-eclipse.html)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with the bellow error:

```
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,oracle.eclipse.tools.rest.lib,8.4.0.201510191754
```

And the solution is to disable **Oracle Enterprise Pack for eclipse**

How to disable this package see the picture bellow:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse Kepler (at least) allows to specifically reload a software site in the Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites dialog.

It is a cleaner / simpler solution than the workaround explained above (add trailing slash) and it worked for me...

Note: a link to this dialog is also available in the Install New Software dialog.

Answer (score 3):

The workaround I found, is to edit the pre-defined URL link by adding just a trailing “/” to the update site URL.

Option #2 worked for me. I went to Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites, then for each enabled site I added a / to the end of the URL (if it wasn't there already), then clicked Reload.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error (September 2020) during an automatic upgrade.

The solution was to add:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-09
```

to the list of Available Software Sites.

I also disabled:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.15
```

and several more with release numbers earlier than 4.15, but I don't think that was the important part.

Comment: In my case it was https://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.18

Answer (score 2):

2019 Eclipse/CCS

After trying many of the above techniques described here I noticed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11413732/9732768) by Edwin landwealths

The long and short of it is to add the infamous tail "/" and ALSO change "http" to "https". This fixed my issue immediately.

Answer (score 2):

As many already said it is an issue related to the update sites, for me disabling Help → Install new software → “Contact all update sites during install to find required software" fixed the issue for install Sirius.
Put for installing epsilon I disable update site as in the picture

[image: Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but while doing updates. I solved it by

- In **Window->Preferences->Install/Updates->Available Software Sites**, mark the site that is causing the problem and hit the **Reload** button.

Answer (score 1):

For Eclipse Neon I had the mentioned error for Mylyn.

To make it work I had to enable the Mylyn Sites that were **disabled** in the Available Software Sites preference pane. They were unnamed (empty name) but recognizable by their Location column.

After saving, updating Mylyn and restarting eclipse, the Available Software Sites looked like this:
[image: Available Software Sites]

Comment: This fixed it for me (together with the *Contact all update sites during install to find required software* checkbox disabling). But why are these sites disabled at all? Is it dangerous to enable them? Can they break anything by providing incompatibilities?

Answer (score 1):

Probably, my experience with this bug will be needed for someone (including myself too... :) ).

So, I could to add one thing to the mentioned here answers. I mean playing with the trailing "/" symbol in the options, because playing with it does not work in my case. But when I have deleted the `.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2/cache` and the `.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.setup/cache` dirs (names are given relatively to the home dir) and **then** have done the well known procedure with "/", it started to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a few repository URL's saved with HTTPS. I changed them to HTTP and the error was gone.

You can adapt the URL's in the settings: **Preferences -> Install/Update -> Available Software Sites**

Comment: Probably the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Issue seems to be with the outdated sites listed in the `Window -> Preferences -> Available Software Sites`. In this window just update the location of the **Buildship** site.

For the **Buildship**, the correct url for different versions can be found from this main site :
https://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/

For specific versions, navigate further down until you reach the specific version.
For example: https://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e416/releases/3.x/

For the latest updates, use url https://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/latest/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the only solution was a manual installation (the plugin's page explained how to install it from the Eclipse's Help menu and, as an alternative, were to unpack the zip manually).

Comment: I could select the appropriate repository (in my case JBoss repository) in "Help > Install new software" and select the components already installed. They would be successfully udpated.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to install Google App Engine SDK, and received similar errors.
None of the answers worked for me.
I noticed download hangs around 999K, while the full download was about 100MB.

Somehow after trying for the sixth or seventh time, the problem fixed itself :)
So if none of these work for you..  try at least several times, maybe server is overloaded :)

Answer (score 0):

Updating from Kepler SR1 to Kepler SR2 solved this for me. 
I've just installed over the existing installation, so none of my settings were harmed.

Win8.1, 64bit

Answer (score 0):

In the end, something does have to be removed.  I would like to add to the other answers: be sure to check for conflicts.  For me, the EMF (Eclipse Modeling Framework) had somehow gotten out of hand as I had multiple versions listed in windows/preferences.  Removing the conflict allowed for my updates to proceed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was getting the above mentioned errors only for a particular update site and eclipse-java-mars-R. Other update sites were allowing me to update, and, using other versions of Eclipse I was able to install from the update site which was causing problems for my Java Mars R Eclipse.

Deleting the cache folder in /Users/myname/.eclipse/org.eclipse.oomph.p2 solved the problem (my coworker, not me, came up with this solution)

Answer (score 0):

I just got it when installing Maven support in Eclipse for Java EE developers Helios. Solution was just to run Eclipse as Administrator, update went fine after

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was selecting

> Work with: --All Available Sites--

Choosing instead only one specific site from the list did the trick (Neon.2 64bit on Windows)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on **windows 10**.
My eclipse version was installed from an **exe**, downloaded from eclipse site.

What solved for me was to **use the zip version instead**:
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/

Answer (score 0):

Me helped the following solution:

Go to Help->Software Updates, then select the Available Software tab and click the Manage Sites button
Use the Export button to export the sites to a bookmarks.xml file
Open the bookmarks.xml file in your favorite text editor, and add a trailing “/” to any of the site urls which are missing the “/” or remove on the end. Save the changes.
Back in the Manage Sites window within Eclipse, select all of the sites and click the Remove button
Now, click Import and load in the edited bookmarks.xml file

Answer (score 0):

For Oxygen, see [Eclipse Community Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1087520/):

"In my case Oxygen had update URL for Buidship as:
http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e46/releases/2.x

Note: that e46 is Neon version per https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/blob/master/docs/user/Installation.md

once I updated URL to Oxygen version (e47):
http://download.eclipse.org/buildship/updates/e47/releases/2.x

update was successful"

Answer (score 0):

I am using lubuntu( like ubuntu) and I found that when I install ccs, I used sudo cmd, so some file can't be changed by another user, that's why the problem comes up. So in the place I installed ccs, I run the cmd

```
sudo chown -R username:groupname *
```

with `username` and `groupname` are the same as my computer account.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had Spring IDE installed on Eclipse Oxygen. During check for updates it would find updates, then it would fail with the above error.

I then went to the Eclipse Marketplace, clicked on Installed tab and noticed Spring did not come up (it was there before and is currently installed).

Then I searched for Spring IDE (Tools) clicked install, then it notified that some packages were already installed and just needed to be updated.

After completing the install of Spring Tools and restarting, I was able to check for updates and complete the normal software updates.

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest STS, export its site list and import it into yours.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the above solutions worked to resolve some of my errors... it seems that after a while update connections just get corrupted and there is no silver-bullet. Managing updates through the marketplace (Help > Marketplace > 'show updates') allowed me to narrow down the packages with failed dependencies.

Here's what I tried (taken from posts above):

1. switching https to http for software sites
2. running Eclipse as administrator
3. 'disabling' obviously outdated software sites
4. 'enabling' all software sites
5. adding backslashes to the end of software site urls
6. uninstalling and re-installing troublesome software

I was still left with some Mylyn wikitext errors despite trying the suggestions [here](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1080241/)

Eclipse IDE for JavaScript and Web Developers

Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0)
Build id: 20190917-1200

Answer (score 0):

For those who encounter this problem when installing Eclipse Code Recommenders, you could try the [advice from the Eclipse Community Forums](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1099870&goto=1814594&#msg_1814594):

```
Go to Help -> Install new software...
Add a repository: 
    Name: Code Recommenders
    Location: https://repo.eclipse.org/content/shadows/releases.unzip/org/eclipse/recommenders/stable/2.5.4/stable-2.5.4.zip-unzip/
```

I guess this approach can be used for other archived projects, too.

Answer (score 0):

See this may be the issue from the publisher side or may be the URL is inactive

you can install it via install new software feature

If you are stuck with eclipse color theme from marketplace then you just need to replace .com to .io from URL as .com URL doesn't exist

to see how to install properly using this feature check this out

https://itsfoss.com/change-eclipse-color-theme/

Answer (score 0):

I got this error during an automatic upgrade to 2023-12.

The solution was to disable old repositories in

Help > Install new software > Manage...

Answer (score -1):

As Mauro said: "you have to remove and re-add the Eclipse Project Update site, so that its metadata are re-calculated." - works as workaround