# An error occurred while collecting items to be installed (Access is denied)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I'm getting the error given below when I try to install the upgrade from Eclipse and it goes like half way and then throw the error.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Program%20Files/eclipse/.
C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins\org.jboss.netty_3.2.4.Final-201112281337.jar (Access is denied)
```

Kindly provide the solution.

Thanks

Comment: If it's W7, try starting Eclipse by right-click, `run as administrator`.

Comment: yes its W7 and i did run as administrator and still get the same error.

Comment: When you're upgrading do you have JBoss running? Do you have any java servers running?

Comment: I don't have any java servers or anything just eclipse for android development

Answer (score 25, accepted):

On Windows 7, the Program Files directory is protected so apps can't automatically write there. The simplest solution I've heard is just to install Eclipse into a **user-writable** location instead. For example, `C:\Java\Eclipse`

You should be able to just move your entire eclipse directory, there's no registry entries or anything else that ties Eclipse to the place where you extracted it.

[Edit]
Have you checked that the directory it is complaining about i actually writable? Other than that, I really don't have any ideas. I haven't worked on Windows in several years and never with Win7. My only other suggestion is to just download the latest Eclipse, install it to a new location (do NOT intall it over top of your existing Eclipse), and point it to your existing workspace.

Comment: same thing i moved to new location and here is the error message `An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/JAVA/eclipse/.
C:\JAVA\eclipse\plugins\org.jboss.netty_3.2.4.Final-201112281337.jar (Access is denied)`

Answer (score 79):

If you have problems using the location: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/,
try editing the location by replacing "http" with "https" or the other way round.

Comment: My ADT bundle from the Android Developer Site had the "http" version of the URL preset. I had to add another one and paste in the URL with "https" to get it to work.

Comment: Replacing http for https worked for me!  Wasted couple of hours on this problem.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Thanks! This worked great!

`Go to Help -> Install New Software -> Click "Available Software Sites" link -> Select "Android Developer Tools Update Site" -> Click "Edit" Button -> Change the http:// in "Location" text box to "https://".`

Comment: Thanks man , btw did u guys encounter any problems after updated?

Answer (score 12):

I just solved this problem by unchecking `Read only` checkbox of the `Program Files/eclipse` folder on win7.

Apply to all files and folders.

Comment: There was no "Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/Program%20Files/eclipse/" message during the installation in my case. But I after `unchecked Read Only`on Eclipse folder, I was able to install a plugin (Weblogic server).

Answer (score 5):

I had also the ADT Bundle that had the HTTP as update url.
Changing it to **HTTPS** solved the problem for me.

Comment: This answer is an exact duplicate of an answer 1 year before... Please upvote to show appreciation instead of duplicating

Comment: sorry, must have overseen that :-(

Answer (score 4):

None of the above worked for me.

Instead, I tried installing the plugins I needed via the Eclipse Market Place, and that worked without issue.

1. Click "Help" Menu.
2. Click "Eclipse Marketplace..." menu item.
3. Enter the name of the plugin you want.
4. Click "Install" when the plugin appears in the Marketplace List.
5. Restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

if you do not wish to change the eclipse directory, then start eclipse as administrator (right click run as administrator) and install the feature again. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error on my ubuntu box until I ran eclipse as root and installed from there:

$ gksudo eclipse

Eclipse was trying to download the packages to /usr/lib/* where I don't have write permissions

Answer (score 1):

Changing from https:// to http:// worked for me

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Installig Eclispe ADT from market place  solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem very easily.

**Go to** Control Panel **->** Network and Sharing Center **->** Windows Firewall **->** Turn off Windows Firewall

And try to install again and see the magic :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I entered:

**Error Log** - found "An error occurred while collecting items to be installed" - **right click** and select **"Open Log"**. From there I know what goues wrong(in my case PMD). I solve the problem in one project and all works ok.

Answer (score 0):

If there are any proxy networks are configured remove them till plugins are installed