# Android: Installing Juno Subversive in New eclipse ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, subversive

I just installed the new "`adt-bundle-windows`" From the [android.developers](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) site.

After creating a new workspace i tried installing the juno subversive to create a connection to my team's SVN

I open Help--> install new software --> and chose "Juno-http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno".
from the new list items, I opened Collaboration and checked all the subversive plug-ins
when the installation process starts everything is going great until i get this error:
"Installing software has encountered a problem
an error occurred while collecting items to be installed"

and on details box it says:

```
"An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.0.0.v201210310015-519525"
```

[Here](https://fbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn1/736160_10151268694909504_1354274389_o.jpg) is a print Screen of the problem

what can be the problem and what can be done to fix it?

Comment: anybody else had this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544071/an-error-occurred-while-collecting-items-to-be-installed-access-is-denied)

In short there are two likely solutions.

1. Go to Help>Install New Software>Available Software Sites> Edit Android Developer Tools Update Site. Change the http to https.
2. The location you are installing to is read only.

Comment: This has solved MY problem when trying to intall Subversive on Android Development Tools 23.0. This needs way more votes!