# Android for Maven Eclipse - solution not found

Tags: android, eclipse, maven

I am trying to upgrade my eclipse and ADT after google's update to the Android SDK 23 totally hosed my whole environment.  I have the latest eclipse luna, I have installed the latest ADK. But when going to the eclipse marketplace for the Android to Maven Eclipse plugin, I am getting this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.standard, 
phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android,1.0.1
No repository found containing:   
org.eclipse.update.feature,me.gladwell.eclipse.m2e.android.feature,1.0.1
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544071/an-error-occurred-while-collecting-items-to-be-installed-access-is-denied Check this link

Comment: Don't see how that helps...  Eclipse can't find the repository, my permissions are fine I think. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Reported as an issue on m2e-android issue list.

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/229

OK, I think I got it sorted. When installing the plugin from Eclipse Market place, in the "Confirm selected features", uncheck "com.android.ide.eclipse.adt", that'll let you install m2e-android plugin correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue caused by the update to m2e 1.5 which causes install problems:

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/220

I suggest you downgrade to Luna and m2e 1.4 and try to install with ADT 23.