# Install pydev on eclipse juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev, eclipse-juno

I just downloaded a fresh copy of `eclipse 4.2.1` and tried to install `PyDev`, I keep getting the below error:

```
 An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
    session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.aptana.interactive_console,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.aptana.shared_core,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.red_core,2.7.1.2012100913
    No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,2.7.1.2012100913
```

I also tested to install `PyDev` on `eclipse 4.2` and got the same error.

Comment: This is a bug in Eclipse. Next time you could try this workaround http://stackoverflow.com/a/7739677/207764

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing different versions of `eclipse` and getting the same error.
I downloaded the `PyDev Zip files` instead and placed and unpacked in `eclipse/dropins`, restarted eclipse and it is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

For PyDev in eclipse use this URL :

http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates/site.xml

i.e. in your eclipse=>Help=>Install new software=>Add=>Location
: *use above URL*

After eclipse restart
Go to Window=>preferences=>PyDev=>Interpreters=>Python Interpreters=>provide python path