# No repository found containing: osgi.bundle and org.eclipse.update.feature

Tags: android, eclipse, github, egit

I am trying to link my Android app to a Github repository.

Following the EGit User Guide, I have first created a new Git repository, but when trying to add to version control ("Team" -> "Add to version control"), this option is not on my list options, either push, commit, merge and many others. I can only chose from Apply Patch or Share Project.

So I am guessing I am missing some Software from the **Collaboration** section. So then I try to install the missing Git stuff: the command line interface and the Mylyn Versions Connector.

And when I try to install the Software, eclipse encounters a problem according to some repository errors: `osgi.boundle` and `org.eclipse.update.feature`.

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>
> No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.iplog,2.1.0.201209190230-r
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.pgm,2.1.0.201209190230-r
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit.pgm,2.1.0.201209190230-r
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.ui,2.1.0.201209190230-r
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.git.core,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.git,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.git.ui,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.versions.core,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>   No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.versions,1.0.2.v20120916-120
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.versions.ui,1.0.2.v20120916-1200
>   No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.kohsuke.args4j,2.0.12.v200910131500

I have been looking for some other posts, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages) about repository errors, where they suggested to remove the update site and installing it again. I have already done it but I keep getting the same error.

Actually I have the following available Software sites:

- Android Developer Tools Update Site : *dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/*
- Eclipse Updates: *download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.2*
- Eclipse Update Site 4.3 : *download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3milestones*
- Juno: *download.eclipse.org/releases/juno*

I am using ADT Build: v21.0.1-543035 on Windows 7 - 64 bits.

Comment: I don't know about the EGit problem you mention. But for the `No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,...` problem you might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/15897080/5108777.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line interface and the Mylyn Versions Connector are both optional and not required for the common use cases.

Use *Share Project...* to first connect the project to the newly created Git repository. After that, you should have more options in the team menu. Then you can add files to version control using *Add to Index*.

As for why installing the additional features doesn't work, maybe you picked the wrong update site. Currently, EGit 2.2 is the newest stable release (and soon 2.3). So maybe you need to update to the newest version first before installing additional features.

Comment: Thank you, I started again the tutorial from the beggining and now it works correctly.