# This Android SDK Requires ADT version 22.6.1 or above

Tags: eclipse-adt

As per my title. I have been using Eclipse happily for months but it has now thrown a wobbly (I think it was due to me adding API 19 to the SDK).

Anyway I deleted the SDK and Eclipse and reinstalled them both.
They are in a folder called development in C:\Program Files (x86) - the same as the Java file.

So I loaded up Eclipse and no errors so thought I'd update the SDK with:
    Android SDK Tools 22.6.1
    API 19 - SDK Platform and ARM EABI

The SDK has the following ticked:

```
Android SDK Tools = 22.6.1

Android SDK Platform-tools = 19.0.1

Android SDK Build-tools = 19

SDK Platform (API 19)

ARM EABI v7a System Image (API 19)

Android Support Library 19.0.1 (Extras)

Google USB Driver (Extras)
```

To update the ADT I have gone to:

```
Help > Install New Software
```

STEP 1

Ran using 22 - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
Which brings up:

Developer Tools

NDK plugins

I tick them both but they say both are already installed.

STEP 2

Ran using Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
(Same as before but without the s in https)
Which brings up:

Developer Tools

NDK plugins

I tick them both but they say both are already installed.

This is the second time round. When I did it first time it did install stuff.

Also my code in a project I created fresh has lots of red lines (android.os, Activity, Bundle etc):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class LapMaster extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lap_master);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.lap_master, menu);
        return true;
    } 
}
```

This looks like a relatively new thing and I have followed other answers but I'm still not getting anywhere?

Anything I may have missed?

Edit:

On the screen

```
Help > Install new Software
```

When I click what is already installed? and go to Installed Software I can see Android Developer Tools there but it is version 22.3.0 and when I expand the node it is blank underneath and then has ADT Package - all are 22.3.0?

Is this to do with ADT Package?

I keep getting an error setting up the SDK location too.

```
Windows > Preferences
```

I use: C:\Program Files (x86)\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk

But it doesn't let me click apply or OK to accept it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have finally fixed it.

I uninstalled the adt package and reinstalled it.

This time I updated the ADT before the SDK, not sure if this was the issue.

This is what I did:

I run Eclipse and all is fine.

```
Go to Help > Check for updates
```

It does some stuff...took an age

Then "No updates could be found"

```
Go to Help > About ADT and Build is still 22.3.0 (I'm trying to get 22.6.1).

Go to Help > Install New Software

Select Android Developer Tools Update Site - http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

Tick Developer Tools

Click next
```

"Already installed so an update will be performed instead"

```
Click next

Accept terms
```

I got an error and I found this useful in resolving it:
I found the link here useful [What to do about Eclipse's "No repository found containing: ..." error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages) if anyone is having errors when performing the update