# Can't update eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Trying to update existing eclipse indtallation ...following error. Can someone help ? Why no repository ?

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.browser,3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.gettingstarted,3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.quicksearch,3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard.ui,3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.runtime.source,1.7.0.20120703164200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.core.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.core,0.9.0.201401250701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.javafx,2.2.0.201401250701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.osgi,0.9.0.201401250701
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.fx.osgi.util,0.9.0.201401250701
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.quicksearch.feature,3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.dashboard,3.6.0.201407080544-RELEASE
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14170852/639753) helped me. Maybe it'll help you.

Comment: Indeed the answer linked by @Xeon helped my colleague get by another issue related to unavailable repositories.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue because multiple versions of spring were installed.
it solved by removing the bad version (preferences > available software sites > ...)

Answer (score 0):

try to reload the descriptor

- look at preferences > available software sites > {select-url-of-spring} and "reload"