# Aptana installation in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, aptana

Just install a new Eclipse Juno
Trying to install Aptana Studion Plugin for eclipse,
giving this error

"An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=DefaultProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,23.0.3.1327240 "

the plugin was working perfectly on my initial eclipse IDE.

has anybody experienced this before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[I found this link helpful on this Q.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages)
Simply: Uncheck “Contact all update sites during install to find required software”