# Cannot install PDT in eclipse luna

Tags: plugins, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-luna

I am trying to install PDT in eclipse luna by clicking Help -> Install New Software and using the name PDT and location: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.4. But the installation failed. So I tried to download the pdt zip package from the eclipse site and install it. But nothing helps. The error shown is:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.httpcomponents.httpclient,4.3.6.v201411290715
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.httpcomponents.httpcore,4.3.3.v201411290715
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf,3.4.0.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer,5.0.0.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.identity,3.4.0.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer,3.2.200.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4,1.0.1043.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl,1.0.0.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.ssl,1.0.0.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.ecf.ssl,1.1.0.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.core.feature,1.1.0.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.core.ssl.feature,1.0.0.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.feature,3.9.2.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.feature,3.9.2.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.httpclient4.ssl.feature,1.0.0.v20141221-2352
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.ecf.filetransfer.ssl.feature,1.0.0.v20141221-2352
```

Answer (score 1):

Try dragging it from the MarketPlace to your workspace:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/php-development-tools

If it doesn't work please check this answer: [What to do about Eclipse's "No repository found containing: ..." error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages)

There are many tips to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Select "Contact all update sites during install to find required software".

It's available in "install new software" window footer. You can also try install from marketplace.