# Can't install JBossAS Tools Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jboss

I'm using Eclipse Luna v4.4.2 and I'm trying to install JBoss Tools (Luna) v4.2.3 plugin specifically JBossAS Tools module. I tried all the suggestions in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages) and none of them worked:

> 1. As Mauro said: "you have to remove and re-add the Eclipse Project
>      Update site, so that its metadata are re-calculated." - works as
>      workaround
> 2. Another workaround I found, is to edit the pre-defined
>      URL link by adding just a trailing “/” to the update site URL.
> 3. The third workaround I discoverd accidentaly is to do nothing, but to
>      uncheck the 'Contact all update sites during install to find
>      required software' before checking the URL link.

This is the error I got:

```
*An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.core,3.5.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.feature,3.5.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.jdt.integration,3.5.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.ui,3.5.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.jboss.ide.eclipse.archives.webtools,3.0.3.Final-v20150325-0035-B129...*
```

Comment: Same situation, I tried  all the suggestions and at least, export/import "Available Software Site", restart eclipse, remove and add JBoss Tools (Luna) and that works

Answer (score 0):

Pierre Jean's comment seemed to work for me.

1. Export all sites to xml file.
2. Restart Eclipse
3. Import all sites from xml file.
4. Now Install JBoss AS.

Seems a bit kludgey but I did notice that I had lots of weird entries in my sites before the export.  All the weird ones were not shows after the import.