# Error installing Nodeclipse

Tags: eclipse, node.js, eclipse-luna, nodeclipse

I am trying to install Nodeclipse,I find that when I drag and drop the link into the Eclipse menu,it brings up a dialog to install `ENide`,once I start installing the plugin,a dialog pops up informing me that the `installation encountered a problem`:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,angularjs-eclipse-feature,0.8.0.201501282321
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,minimal-json,0.9.2
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.a.wst.html.webresources.core,0.9.0.201501272159
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.a.wst.html.webresources.ui,0.9.0.201501272159
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.angularjs.core,0.8.0.201501282321
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.angularjs.ui,0.8.0.201501282321
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.html.webresources.feature,0.9.0.201501272159
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,tern-feature,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,tern-jsdt-feature,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,tern-server-nodejs-feature,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.core,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.eclipse,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.eclipse.ide.core,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.eclipse.ide.jsdt,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.eclipse.ide.server.nodejs.core,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.eclipse.ide.server.nodejs.ui,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.eclipse.ide.tools.core,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,tern.eclipse.ide.tools.feature,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.eclipse.ide.tools.ui,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.eclipse.ide.ui,0.9.0.201501272204
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,tern.server.nodejs,0.9.0.201501272204
```

How can I avoid these errors and perform a successful installation of `Nodeclipse` on the server.

I have tried it using the `http://nodeclipse.org/updates/` and other binary url but both of those resulted in failure in my case.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Nodeclipse update site has become slower.

**Carefully read http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/** page it has several options including : Enide Studio
drag-n-drop, using update site URL (be sure to

> Uncheck "Contact all updates site during install to find required software"

)
offline zip archive installing, p2f file and CLI util `nodeclipse install nodejs`.

http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/ is composite repository that includes also Tern, Gradle, Maven, Mylyn
(Just run `nodeclipse list` from folder with `eclipse[.exe]`)

Try installing less feature at a time from smaller repository like
`http://www.nodeclipse.org/updates/1/`

And for Windows there all-in-one downloadable package "Enide Studio 2014"

Help like collaboration is needed for releasing packages for other OSes,
so always welcoming to start dialog on https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues