# Eclipse update (rarely) works: No repository found containing -- many entries

Tags: eclipse

I don't understand, why Eclipse update made so unreliable? Approximately each time I use it, I meet some problem!

For example, now I meet bunch of delirium below. Disabling "Contact All Software Sites" does not help.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.5.2.20150413-2214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.5.2.20150413-2214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.5.2.20150413-2214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple,1.5.2.20150413-2214
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core,3.15.0.v20150204-0622
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ide,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.ui,3.15.0.v20150203-1905
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.core,1.7.0.v20150113-2201
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.builds.ui,1.7.0.v20150113-2201
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity.core,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.core,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.feed,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications.ui,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.http.core,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.ui,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.screenshots,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.ui,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.workbench,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.tasks.ui,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.context.ui,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.cvs.core,1.7.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.debug.ui,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.core,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery.ui,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.git.core,1.7.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.git.ui,1.7.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.help.ui,3.15.0.v20150113-0037
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.core,1.7.0.v20150113-2201
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.ui,1.7.0.v20150113-2201
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide.ant,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide.ui,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.java.tasks,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.java.ui,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.core,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor.ui,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.resources.ui,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.bugs,3.15.0.v20150113-0037
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core,3.15.0.v20150311-2102
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.core,3.15.0.v20150113-0037
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.index.ui,3.15.0.v20150113-0037
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.search,3.15.0.v20150113-0037
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ui,3.15.0.v20150316-1810
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.team.cvs,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.team.ui,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.versions.core,1.7.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.versions.ui,1.7.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence.core,2.4.0.v20150312-2106
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.confluence.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.context.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core,2.4.0.v20150316-1438
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core.ant,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.core.osgi,2.4.0.v20150309-1638
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.html.core,2.4.0.v20150309-2304
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown.core,2.4.0.v20150316-1818
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.markdown.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.mediawiki.core,2.4.0.v20150309-1638
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.mediawiki.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tasks.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1638
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.textile.core,2.4.0.v20150312-2106
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.textile.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tracwiki.core,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.tracwiki.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.twiki.core,2.4.0.v20150309-1638
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.twiki.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1623
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.ui,2.4.0.v20150309-1638
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals,1.3.0.201502251423
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.local,1.3.0.201502201446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.process,1.3.0.201502201446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.serial,1.3.0.201502201446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.ssh,1.3.0.201502201446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tcf.te.ui.terminals.telnet,1.3.0.201502201446
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tm.terminal,3.3.1.201502251211
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tm.terminal.serial,2.1.400.201502240653
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tm.terminal.ssh,2.1.400.201502240653
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tm.terminal.telnet,2.1.400.201502240653
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature,1.5.2.20150413-2215
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature,3.15.0.v20150204-0622
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.builds,1.7.0.v20150113-2201
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.identity,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.notifications,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.http,1.7.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.cvs,1.7.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.discovery,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.git,1.7.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson,1.7.0.v20150113-2201
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.monitor,3.15.0.v20150112-2323
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.ide,3.15.0.v20150113-0037
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature,3.15.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.versions,1.7.0.v20150113-0039
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature,2.4.0.v20150316-1818
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.mylyn_feature,3.15.0.v20150316-1810
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tcf.te.core.terminals,1.3.0.201502201518
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.tcf.te.terminals.feature,1.3.0.201502251423
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.tm.terminal,3.7.1.201502251223
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.tm.terminal.serial,3.7.0.201502251223
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.tm.terminal.ssh,3.7.0.201502251223
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.tm.terminal.telnet,3.7.0.201502251223
```

Comment: Probably you don't have an update site configured which contains those particular versions of the plugins - perhaps they are for a different release of Eclipse.

Comment: Why they are proposed to update then? Note that I am just calling "Update" feature and then pressing "Next" button. It should either propose me to update what it can, and if it can't, it should not propose me this then.

Comment: Take a look at this.  It solved a similar issue for me.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages

Comment: I'm just curious what you're trying to download or install. I just ran into this issue today trying to update various Mylyn components.

Comment: Second answer in the question referred by @Beeps got rid of the problem in my side: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15897080/5108777

Comment: @Dims, did any of the answers solved your question? Can you mark this question as solved?

Answer (score 16):

I solved this by disabling all superflous update sites.

This is the base update sites I ended up with:

- EGit P2 Repository    http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates    Enabled
- Mylyn for Eclipse Luna    http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/luna Enabled
- The Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) software repository  - http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/luna  Enabled
- The Eclipse Project Updates   http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4 Enabled

I also had this update site enabled:

Luna    http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna   Disabled

which I had to disable to get rid of the egit errors. Turns out http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna contains egit and eclipse doesn't manage to choose between that version and the one in "EGit P2"... (omg)

I assume http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4 also overlap with the releases/luna repo

I also diasbled all update sites pointing to older releases (kepler, etc)

Answer (score 13):

Something happened in m2e plugin, so to get rid of this exception you have to disable its repository. Check the selection in the screenshot below:

Go to:

Help -> Install new software -> Available software sites -> Disable selection (from screenshot)

[image]

Comment: I had to clean `<eclipse folder>/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository/cache` directory and restart Eclipse to apply changes

Comment: I follow this step but does not resolved. Please provide the any other solution.Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you try to add new software/plugin to eclipse it will also try to install/update the existing software sites. You can disable or remove those are causing issues and you don't want any updates from those software sites.
In my case where I am using Luna I had to disable "Mylyn 3.18 for Eclipse 3.8, 4.4 and 4.5 - http://download.eclipse.org/mylyn/releases/latest"  and disable " http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases". The updates are not working may be because of mismatch in the eclipse version and plugin (not sure, please correct me if I am wrong).
The way to disable these software sites in eclipse is windows -> preferences -> Availabe software sites

Answer (score 4):

In my case the problem was caused by not having the m2eclipse update site ( http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ ) in `Help -> Install new software -> Available software sites`.

The problem dissapeared after adding it there.