# Unable to install vaadin plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, vaadin, eclipse-marketplace

I am using eclipse (Kepler) and I want to install the Vaadin plugin.

When I am installing the same from Eclipse Market place, it is showing me the below error. Any idea on how to install ?

[image]

Comment: See if this post helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why Eclipse Marketplace sends your Eclipse Kepler to http://vaadin.com/eclipse as the Kepler compatible update site is http://vaadin.com/eclipse/3.5.

You can install manually from the correct update site through Help -> Install New Software

If you want to use the newest plugin, including the visual designer, you need to update to at least Eclipse Luna