# Getting error while updating Eclipse updates

Tags: eclipse

I am facing problem while taking updates for Eclipse, my error is :

An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session context was:(profile=C__Users_punam_eclipse_java-mars_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=). No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jst.common.project.facet.core,1.4.400.v201403261500?

Comment: `No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,...` shows up in a lot of SO questions. The answer that worked for me is #2 in http://stackoverflow.com/a/15897080/5108777

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have issues with your internal Eclipse cache.
I would suggest to rename (not delete!)
- USERHOME.p2\pool
- USERHOME.eclipse\org.eclipse.oomph.p2
and try the update again.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I should wait and try your solution. But I am very impatient I already uninstall the eclipse and installed it again and above problem resolved. Next time if I face same issue I will try it. Again many thanks for replying.