# Eclipse update fails with error

Tags: java, eclipse

I get the below error when trying to update eclipse

```
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.archetype.common,1.6.2.20150902-0001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.discovery,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.editor.xml,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.feature,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.jdt.ui,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.launching,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.lifecyclemapping.defaults,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender,1.6.1.20150625-2338
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration,1.6.1.20150625-2338
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature,1.6.1.20150625-2338
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer,1.6.2.20150902-0001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime,1.6.2.20150902-0001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple,1.6.2.20150902-0001
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.model.edit,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.core,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.profiles.ui,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring,1.6.2.20150902-0002
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.m2e.scm,1.6.2.20150902-0002
```

Comment: seems like a bug https://github.com/eclipse/buildship/issues/488

Comment: how will it get resolved? wait for a bug fix.....

Comment: This would help ,to fix this error --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/15897080/9378962