# eclipse eclemma - No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma

Tags: java, eclipse, eclemma

i had eclemma installed on oxygen Version: Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
Build id: 20180405-1200 and working, but it seems gone from the menu.

trying to update, gets the message below. removing and reinstalling does not make any coverage items appear in the menu. so i am stuck in a loop.

thanks

edit: photon has a different version. and photon *has* a coverage button.

```
photon
    EclEmma Java Code Coverage  3.1.0.201801310113  org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group   Eclipse EclEmma
    Eclipse Java Development Tools  3.14.0.v20180308-0630   org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group   Eclipse.org
    Eclipse Platform    4.8.0.v20180308-0630    org.eclipse.platform.feature.group  Eclipse.org
    Eclipse RCP 4.8.0.v20180308-0630    org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group   Eclipse.org

oxygen
    EclEmma Java Code Coverage  3.1.0.201804041601  org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group   Eclipse EclEmma
    Eclipse Java Development Tools  3.13.4.v20180330-0919   org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group   Eclipse.org
    Eclipse Platform    4.7.3.v20180330-0640    org.eclipse.platform.feature.group  Eclipse.org
    Eclipse RCP 4.7.3.v20180330-0640    org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group   Eclipse.org



An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=C__Users_ray_eclipse_java-oxygen3_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma.core,3.1.0.201805281015
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma.doc,3.1.0.201805281015
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.eclemma.ui,3.1.0.201805281015
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.eclemma.feature,3.1.0.201805281015
```

Comment: Which repositories are you letting it search?

Comment: i have no idea, whatever eclipse usually does i suppose.

Comment: From which menu? Top, in `Run`? Toolbar? Context menu? Is there `Eclipse EclEmma` icon in `Help -> About Eclipse`? is there `EclEmma Core` and `EclEmma UI` in `Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details -> Plug-inst` ? Maybe add screenshot(s) for clarity? Also pay attention on selected perspective - e.g. context menu shows `Coverage As` even in `Resource` or `Java Browsing` perspectives, but top menu shows `Coverage As` in `Java` and `Debug` and not  in `Resource` or `Java Browsing` perspectives.

Answer (score 8):

I had exactly the same problem, and was able to update EclEmma using the Marketplace at `Help -> Eclipse Marketplace` (search for EclEmma; an update button will be shown).

Comment: There is no problem with http://update.eclemma.org/ - it is not intended to be browsable, but files are downloadable from it, marketplace points exactly to it.

Comment: What is really weird in initial question - is that EclEmma is part of Java Oxygen.3a package, so how can it disappear? Right now tried to uninstall it and after restart Eclipse asked to install it back and did it without marketplace from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen/ which is preconfigured in Oxygen.  One can use marketplace for upgrades of EclEmma to the newer version than the one that was shipped with Oxygen.3a, but this is other story.

Comment: And BTW messages "No repository found" according to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=290782 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages might actually be a result of unavailability to contact some other repository.

Comment: You are right @Godin, the update site works (for example, http://update.eclemma.org/artifacts.jar is downloadable). It is still strange that the update works via Marketplace and not via the default update process. Ray: You could try one of the three solutions proposed in the the stackoverflow question Godin posted above.

Comment: What is "default update process" ? Usage of http://update.eclemma.org/ in `Help > Install New Software` is equivalent of update via Marketplace. And update process is not an answer on question - why/how magically disappears something that was already installed and part of default distribution/package ?

Comment: Normally the "No repository found containing ..." errors can be fixed with one of the three methods in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages. This is what I tried, but to no avail (same error messages as Ray). However, using the Marketplace it worked. To answer your second question: I installed https://www.eclipse.org/ecoretools/ which required a newer version of EclEmma than the one delivered with my Oxygen.3a, Build id: 20180405-1200, so in my case it was an EclEmma update, not a new installation.

Comment: I was getting all the time the same error with EclEmma, and following this steps update ir perfectly runned.