# Installing software has encountered a problem

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microservices

Using eclipse 2019 and try to install Spring from marketplace. I still new in develop microservices. 
Here is the error that i got :

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=C__Users_samazlan eclipse_java-2019-09_eclipse,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.lsp4e,0.13.1.202001090910 No repository found
>   containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.tm4e.core,0.4.1.201912212242 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.boot.ide.main.feature,4.5.1.202001211302-RELEASE
>   No repository found containing:
>   binary,org.springframework.boot.ide.main.feature_root,4.5.1.202001211302-RELEASE
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.ui.live,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.dash.feature,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.refactoring,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.restart,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.templates,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.validation,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.wizard,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.buildship20,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.buildship30,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.editor.support,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.imports,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.ide.eclipse.xml.namespaces.feature,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls,1.15.0.202001210741 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.tooling.boot.ls.feature,4.5.1.202001210741
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.bosh.ls,1.15.0.202001210741 No
>   repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.tooling.bosh.ls.feature,4.5.1.202001210741
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.cloudfoundry.manifest.ls,1.15.0.202001210741
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.tooling.cloudfoundry.manifest.ls.feature,4.5.1.202001210741
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.concourse.ls,1.15.0.202001210741
>   No repository found containing:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.springframework.tooling.concourse.ls.feature,4.5.1.202001210741
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.jdt.ls.commons,4.5.1.202001210741
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.commons,4.5.1.202001210741
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springframework.tooling.ls.eclipse.gotosymbol,4.5.1.202001210741
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.cloudfoundry.client.v2,3.9.12.202001201914-CI-B2372
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.core,3.9.12.202001132314-CI-B489
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.core,3.9.12.202001132314-CI-B489
>   No repository found containing:
>   osgi.bundle,org.springsource.ide.eclipse.commons.frameworks.ui,3.9.12.202001132314-CI-B489

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do about Eclipse's "No repository found containing: ..." error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470802/what-to-do-about-eclipses-no-repository-found-containing-error-messages)

Comment: No..i redi update my eclipse still got same error

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem whilst doing a round of updates.

Go to  Window > preferences

[image: window preferences]

go to install/update > Available software sites

[image: install update to available software sites]

scroll with the bottom scrollbar to the right so the location urls are in view and locate the tm4e url. http://download.eclipse.org/tm4e/snapshots
Select it and click the edit button.

[image: find and edit url]

Add a slash at the end of the url.

[image: adding a slash]

Hit apply and close and now check for updates.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have unchecked 'Contact all update sites during install to find required software'.